# How to plot a hourly rainfall time series

Tags: r

My time series has a following format, I have to plot a hourly time series, can anyone know how to do it. I would like not to plot -9999 values only real precipitation values

```
**Precipitation                             
YY      MM  DD  HH  365         877         
YY      MM  DD  HH  5643798.4   5623228.2   4622030    4622789      4621870
YY      MM  DD  HH  4620564.8   4623768.4   5634890    5633638      5633942
YY      MM  DD  HH  991         5779        53718629    53718621    53718622**
1995    9   1   0    -9999      5.5        -9999       -9999    -9999
1995    9   1   1    -9999      5.7        -9999       -9999    -9999
1995    9   1   2     -9999     6.8        -9999       -9999    -9999
1995    9   1   3     -9999     5.6        -9999       -9999    -9999
1995    9   1   4     -9999     5.9        -9999       -9999    -9999
1995    9   1   5     -9999     5.2        -9999       -9999    -9999
1995    9   1   6      -9999      8        -9999       -9999    -9999
1995    9   1   7     -9999     4.5        -9999       -9999    -9999
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`, `lubridate` and the `tidyverse`

Assuming you structure your df like this:

```
> prec_df
# A tibble: 8 × 9
Year Month   Day  Hour    x0 Precipitation    x1    x2    x3
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1995     9     1     0 -9999           5.5 -9999 -9999 -9999
2  1995     9     1     1 -9999           5.7 -9999 -9999 -9999
3  1995     9     1     2 -9999           6.8 -9999 -9999 -9999
4  1995     9     1     3 -9999           5.6 -9999 -9999 -9999
5  1995     9     1     4 -9999           5.9 -9999 -9999 -9999
6  1995     9     1     5 -9999           5.2 -9999 -9999 -9999
7  1995     9     1     6 -9999           8.0 -9999 -9999 -9999
8  1995     9     1     7 -9999           4.5 -9999 -9999 -9999
```

You can use:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
prec_df %>% mutate(utc = lubridate::ymd_h( str_c( Year, Month, Day, Hour, sep =":") ) ) %>% 
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = utc, y = Precipitation))
```

Comment: my time series is very big, is it possible to let me know how to plot at least 2 station data. In X axis-Time (Year, Month, Day, Hour format) and in Y axis-Rainfall data.

Comment: Do you mean just having two Precipitation columns? You can add two ```geom_line```s with the different column names

Comment: but first of all i have to find a way to plot the graph, i am new to R and the above mention command is not plotting what i wanted. All i want is how to write a proper code to plot my hourly time series

Comment: how is it different from what you wanted? I can run my code above and plot a time series of the Precipitation column.

Comment: > rf>mutate(utc = lubridate::ymd_h( str_c( YY, MM, DD, HH, sep =":") ) )      
Error in mutate(utc = lubridate::ymd_h(str_c(YY, MM, DD, HH, sep = ":"))) : 
  could not find function "mutate"
> rf%>%mutate(utc = lubridate::ymd_h( str_c( YY, MM, DD, HH, sep =":") ) )
Error in rf %>% mutate(utc = lubridate::ymd_h(str_c(YY, MM, DD, HH, sep = ":"))) : 
  could not find function "%>%"............I am getting this error, I file has rf for prec_df, YY instead of year and so on...

Comment: You need to include those packages.  I have edited it above, you may need to install them with ```install.packages``` first as well.

Comment: now i am getting this...> rf%>%mutate(utc = lubridate::ymd_h( str_c( YY, MM, DD, HH, sep =":") ) ) %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = utc, y = X991))
Error in Ops.data.frame(rf %>% mutate(utc = lubridate::ymd_h(str_c(YY,  : 
  list of length 9 not meaningful

Comment: Your dataframe is not in the format I specified, and I don't know from your original question what it looks like.  You can get it exactly and edit your original question with its contents using ```dput(df)```.